# HTML css speech bubble is not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and currently developing a speech bubble but when the text is long it is overlapping on timestamp inside the bubble .I am using `display: inline-block;` in my css . Below is my html and css sample code.

```css
.speech-wrapper{
  padding: 2px 6px;
  
  }
.chatbox {
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top:0px; 
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background: #075698;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  width:inline;
}
.chatbox_other{
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  height:auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top:0px; 
  background: #DCDCDC;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

      .name_other{
         font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 0px  9px;
        color: #1970b0;
      }
    .name_other1{
         font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 0px  9px;
        color: #ba006e;
      }
    .name_other2{
         font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 0px  9px;
        color: #007670;
      }
    .name_other3{
         font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 0px  9px;
        color: #3b0256;
      }
    .name_other4{
         font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 0px  9px;
        color: #00512b;
      }
    .name_other5{
         font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 0px  9px;
        color: #a91024;
      }
      .name_other6{
         font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 0px  9px;
        color: #b8471b;
      }
      .name_other7{
         font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 0px  9px;
        color: #7f1c7d;
      }
   
.timestamp_other{
        font-size: 11px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase; color: #999
}  
.timestamp{
        font-size: 11px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase; color: #fff
      }
/* speech bubble 13 */
      .name{
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px 0px  9px;
        color: #ffffff;
      }
 

.triangle.left-top:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -10px;
  right: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 22px solid;
  border-color: #DCDCDC transparent transparent transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}

.triangle.right-top:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    border: 32px solid;
    border-color: #075698 transparent transparent 
      transparent;
   z-index: -1;
} 
   .alt{
      margin: 0 0 0 60px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="speech-wrapper"><div class="chatbox triangle right-top"><div class="txt"><p class="name">Apple TestUser1</p><span>Hi</span><p class="timestamp">10:20 pm</p></div><div class="bubble-arrow">
</div></div>
  <div class="speech-wrapper"><div class="chatbox_other triangle left-top"><div class="txt"><p class="name">Apple TestUser1</p><span>Hi hegi</span><p  class="timestamp">10:20 pm</p></div><span class="bubble-arrow">
</span></div>
```

Any clue on this behavior is helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Are you tring to do some thing like below..

Changes are:

1. Added `padding-bottom: 25px;` in `.chatbox_other` & `.chatbox`
2. Added `margin-bottom: 5px;` in `.timestamp`

```css
.speech-wrapper {
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

.chatbox {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #075698;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  width: inline;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.chatbox_other {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background: #DCDCDC;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.name_other {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 0px 9px;
  color: #1970b0;
}

.name_other1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 0px 9px;
  color: #ba006e;
}

.name_other2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 0px 9px;
  color: #007670;
}

.name_other3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 0px 9px;
  color: #3b0256;
}

.name_other4 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 0px 9px;
  color: #00512b;
}

.name_other5 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 0px 9px;
  color: #a91024;
}

.name_other6 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 0px 9px;
  color: #b8471b;
}

.name_other7 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 0px 9px;
  color: #7f1c7d;
}

.timestamp_other {
  font-size: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #999;
}

.timestamp {
  font-size: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* speech bubble 13 */

.name {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px 0px 9px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.triangle.left-top:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -10px;
  right: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 22px solid;
  border-color: #DCDCDC transparent transparent transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}

.triangle.right-top:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 32px solid;
  border-color: #075698 transparent transparent transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}

.alt {
  margin: 0 0 0 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech-wrapper">
  <div class="chatbox triangle right-top">
    <div class="txt">
      <p class="name">Apple TestUser1</p><span>Hi</span>
      <p class="timestamp">10:20 pm</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-arrow">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="speech-wrapper">
    <div class="chatbox_other triangle left-top">
      <div class="txt">
        <p class="name">Apple TestUser1</p><span>Hi Your_Name</span>
        <p class="timestamp">10:20 pm</p>
      </div><span class="bubble-arrow">
</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Amending the style for `timestamp` class should fix the issue.**

The change I did is to float the timestamp to the right and making it a block element so that it remains independent.

```
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
```

The working code snippet is as follows -

```css
.speech-wrapper {
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

.chatbox {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #075698;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  width: inline;
}

.chatbox_other {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background: #DCDCDC;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.timestamp {
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff
}


/* speech bubble 13 */

.name {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.triangle.left-top:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -10px;
  right: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 22px solid;
  border-color: #DCDCDC transparent transparent transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}

.triangle.right-top:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 32px solid;
  border-color: #075698 transparent transparent transparent;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech-wrapper">
  <div class="chatbox triangle right-top">
    <div class="txt">
      <p class="name">Apple TestUser1</p><span>Hi sdsdsd dssssssssssssssssssssssssss</span>
      <p class="timestamp">10:20 pm</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-arrow">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="speech-wrapper">
    <div class="chatbox_other triangle left-top">
      <div class="txt">
        <p class="name">Apple TestUser1</p><span>Hi hegi</span>
        <p class="timestamp">10:20 pm</p>
      </div><span class="bubble-arrow">
</span></div>
```